Lagging Issue In TableView
i have 19 JSON files, and you load this data and perform mapping based on the characters typed in a UITextField. The issue is that the UI becomes stuck and laggy when you scroll or type a lot of characters (e.g., 100 characters) in the UITextField. Even though you're using background threads, the UI still gets stuck. Code Below
func loadBigDataFiles() {
        // Record the start time
        let startTime = Date()

        // Prepare file names for font files
        let fontFiles = (0...19).map { "font\($0).json" }
        var inputStreams: [InputStream] = []

        // Create InputStream for each JSON file
        for fileName in fontFiles {
            if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: nil),
               let stream = InputStream(url: fileURL) {
                inputStreams.append(stream)
            } else {
                print("Failed to create InputStream for file \(fileName)")
            }
        }

        // Load fonts from the input streams
        load(inputStreams: inputStreams)

        // Record the end time
        let endTime = Date()

        // Calculate the execution time
        let executionTime = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        print("Execution time: \(executionTime) seconds")
    }
    func convertData(indexNo: Int, text: String) -> String {
        // Fetch the hash map for the specified index
        let hashMap = fonts[indexNo]
        
        // Initialize an empty result string
        var result = ""
        
        // Iterate over each character in the input text
        for char in text {
            // Convert the character to uppercase and fetch its mapped value from the hashMap
            if let mappedValue = hashMap[char.uppercased().first!] {
                // Append the mapped value to the result, followed by a newline
                result += mappedValue + "\n"
            }
        }
        
        // Return the final result string
        return result
    }


    // Load fonts from input streams
    func load(inputStreams: [InputStream]) {
        for stream in inputStreams {
            do {
                let json = try getJson(from: stream)
                var map: [Character: String] = [:]
                for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" {
                    if let bigText = json[String(char)] {
                        map[char] = bigText
                    }
                }
                fonts.append(map)
            } catch {
                print("Load error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        loaded = true
    } 
**Tableview Function code here**

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 20
     }
     
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BigTextTableViewCell
             
             // Set a placeholder or loading state initially
             cell.configure(name: "Loading...", currentRow: "\(indexPath.row)")
             
             // Asynchronously convert data
             let text = textField.text!
             let index = indexPath.row
             
//         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [self] in
                 // Perform the conversion in a background thread
                 let finalString = bigText.convertData(indexNo: index, text: text)
                 
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     // Update the cell with the result on the main thread
                     if let updatedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BigTextTableViewCell {
                         updatedCell.configure(name: finalString, currentRow: "\(indexPath.row)")
                     }
//                 }
             }
         return cell
     }

I need better guidelines and will send a JSON file so that I can understand where I am making mistakes. This is the data from the JSON file.
{
  "A": "───\r\n╔═╗─\r\n║╬╚╗\n╚══╝",
  "B": "╔╗─\r\n╚╗║\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝",
  "C": "───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╚═╝",
  "D": "─╔╗\r\n╔╝║\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝",
  "E": "───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║╩╣\r\n╚═╝",
  "F": "╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─",
  "G": "╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╠╗║\r\n╚═╝",
  "H": "╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n║║║\r\n╚╩╝",
  "I": "╔╗\r\n╠╣\r\n║║\r\n╚╝",
  "J": "─╔╗\r\n─╠╣\r\n╔╝║\r\n╚═╝",
  "K": "╔╗─\r\n║╠╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╚╩╝",
  "L": "───\r\n╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n╚═╝",
  "M": "────\r\n╔══╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚╩╩╝",
  "N": "────\r\n╔═╦╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚╩═╝",
  "O": "───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝",
  "P": "╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─",
  "Q": "╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╚╗║\r\n─╚╝",
  "R": "───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─",
  "S": "╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╠═║\r\n╚═╝",
  "T": "╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n║╔╣\r\n╚═╝",
  "U": "───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n║║║\r\n╚═╝",
  "V": "─────\r\n╔═╦═╗\r\n╚╗║╔╝\r\n─╚═╝─",
  "W": "────\r\n╔╦╦╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚══╝",
  "X": "───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n╠║╣\r\n╚╩╝",
  "Y": "╔╦╗\r\n║║║\r\n╠╗║\r\n╚═╝",
  "Z": "╔═╗\r\n╠═║\r\n║═╣\r\n╚═╝",
  " ": "───\r\n───\r\n───\r\n───"
}
**i have this string in tableview label but the issue is memory management i have 20 + data set like below but am very tired how to resolve this** 

`───\r\n╔═╗─\r\n║╬╚╗\n╚══╝\n\n╔╗─\r\n╚╗║\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝\n\n───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╚═╝\n\n─╔╗\r\n╔╝║\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝\n\n───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║╩╣\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─\n\n╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╠╗║\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n║║║\r\n╚╩╝\n\n╔╗\r\n╠╣\r\n║║\r\n╚╝\n\n─╔╗\r\n─╠╣\r\n╔╝║\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔╗─\r\n║╠╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╚╩╝\n\n───\r\n╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n╚═╝\n\n────\r\n╔══╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚╩╩╝\n\n────\r\n╔═╦╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚╩═╝\n\n───\r\n╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─\n\n╔═╗\r\n║╬║\r\n╚╗║\r\n─╚╝\n\n───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n║╔╝\r\n╚╝─\n\n╔═╗\r\n║═╣\r\n╠═║\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔╗─\r\n║╚╗\r\n║╔╣\r\n╚═╝\n\n───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n║║║\r\n╚═╝\n\n─────\r\n╔═╦═╗\r\n╚╗║╔╝\r\n─╚═╝─\n\n────\r\n╔╦╦╗\r\n║║║║\r\n╚══╝\n\n───\r\n╔╦╗\r\n╠║╣\r\n╚╩╝\n\n╔╦╗\r\n║║║\r\n╠╗║\r\n╚═╝\n\n╔═╗\r\n╠═║\r\n║═╣\r\n╚═╝

i have try different approach like data save in core data but optimzation in failed seniors please help me how to do this

There isn't enough information here to give a precise answer, but I'll answer what I can
Your code doesn't show the whole issue, we don't know when you are calling loadBigDataFiles, or how often. it looks like you are calling convertData each time you load a cell, on a background thread and then updating it in the main thread.
Why don't you load all the JSON files and convert the data in one go and then store it ready for the TableView to use.
A few suggestions...
Core data should be faster, as the data should already be converted and in a state ready to use, your not loading multiple files and converting JSON and then converting the data which will be more expensive.
try to perform any heavy tasks (loading data, converting data etc) in one go and then make the usable data available to the table view. This will mean that the table view just has to display data and not perform other tasks, so should be faster.
you could also look at using 'prefetching' data for your table view: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

Hi bro i updated the code my isssue is memory management because datasets are very heavy i updated the code last i add a dataset that is issue how i mange this
